# How to load the contents of a hyperlink in same page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webforms

I receive output files(`.html`) from a service. These output files are dumped in a particular directory(`C:\Output\`). I populate hyperlinks in my `Web form` as per the files present in (`C:\Output\`). When user clicks on these hyperlinks, user is redirected to the contents of local (`.html`) file. Until here it's done.

Now **I wish to load the contents in the same page itself** when hyperlink is clicked.

Now there are many *Q & A* available which might seems similar but don't help me due to the foll difference that

The hyperlinks are generated **dynamically** based on the files present.

I see a lot of answers mentioning to use

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#content1">Show content 1</a>
    <a href="#content2">Show content 2</a>
    <a href="#content3">Show content 3</a>
</div>
```

and then a `javascript function` for toggling.

This is for static content I wish to have the same for dynamic content.

Thanks.

Comment: Being a beginner in web applications I might have  missed something silly or  in case some additional data is missing then please let me know.

Comment: do you want to show another html file in a html file. is this what you looking for?

Comment: @Kerim Yes, It's like a master site with certain links for toggling.

Comment: please search iframe html element. It will provide your expectation.